# Two balls are drawn at random from a bag (probability)

Tags: probability, proof-verification

**Part 1: Two balls are drawn at random from a bag, there are $2$ white balls, $3$ black balls, what is the probability the second ball is white? with replacement, and without replacement**

*Without replacement:*

$\frac{5!}{(5-2)!} = 20$ permutations

$\frac{(_2C_1)(_1C_1)+(_3C_1)(2C_1)}{20}=\frac8{20}=\frac25$

My reasoning : pick $1$ white out of $2$ then pick remaining $1$ white ball
OR pick $1$ black out of $3$, and $1$ white out of $2$. divided by number of permutations.

*With replacement:*

$(_5C_1)(_5C_1)=25$

$\frac{(_3C_1)(_2C_1)+(_2C_1)(_2C_1)}{25}=\frac{10}{25}=\frac 25$

reasoning : pick $1$ black out of $3$, pick $1$ white out of $2$ OR pick $1$ white out of $2$ , pick $1$ white out of $2.$

**part 2: If we want both balls of same color? with replacement, without replacement**

*Without replacement:*

$_5C_2=10$

$\frac{_2C_2+_3C_2}{_5C_2}=\frac 4{10}=\frac 25$

reasoning: pick 2 white out of 2 Or 2 black out of 3

*With replacement:*

$(_5C_1)(_5C_1)=25$

$\frac{_3C_2+_2C_2}{25}=\frac4{25}$

**But the answer should be** $\frac{(_3C_1)(_3C_1)+(_2C_1)(_2C_1)}{25}=\frac{13}{25}$

Could someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: I added the tag (proof-verification) which is synonymous with (solution-verfication) because it seems you are seeking verification of your solutions.  Else, I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: yes sorry exactly, that my logic is ok and answers, quite unsure!

Comment: Note:  $\frac {10}{25}=\frac 25$ so both answers to part $1$ are the same (which is correct, though I am not clear on your reasoning for "with replacement").  For part $2$, without replacement is correct but with replacement ought to be $\frac 25\times \frac 25 +\frac 35\times \frac 35=\frac {13}{25}$.  Intutitively, it is a lot easier to match the colors if you replace.

Comment: For part 1 "with replacement": each draw is the same as the first, so the answer is $\frac 25$ .

Comment: ahh thanks i see my mistake of the last one. It should be (3c1)(3c1)+(2c1)(2c1)=9+4=13/25

Comment: For reasons of delicacy, one traditionally phrases these problems as being about drawing balls from an urn, not from a bag....

Comment: By symmetry of the sample spaces involved, $P(W_1) = P(W_2) = 2/5,$ with or without replacement. [Without replacement, for $W_2$ it is understood that you don't know the result on the first trial so it's $P(W_2) = P(W_1W_2)+P(B_1W_2),$ not $P(W_2|W_1)$ or $P(W_2| B_1).]$